# Bootstrap : navbar parent menu selection issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using **bootstrap** **sticky  menu**  ,  now for **dropdown** when I hover over parent menu sub menu is displayed but parent menu is not highlighted as I go one level down . [image]

here you can see washing and cleaning comes under services .

What I want is the menu services should be highlighted as washing  is at the moment  this is my `html` structure

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Cleaning </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Washing</a></li>
     </ul><!-- end dropdown-menu -->
 </li>
</ul>
```

http://www.bootply.com/j4dAggAcCh

Comment: I looked at your Bootply, you're overriding the intended functionality of Bootstrap (which is to not open dropdowns on `hover`) and I'm not sure how to go about fixing that. You may need to look into a non-bootstrap solution for that particular dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing the :focus on your menu link. This keeps your link highlighted when your in a subnav.

So what I should try in your CSS:

```
.dropdown-toggle:focus{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Well it **might** if your example code and your bootstrap code were the same.. You don't have the class `.dropdown-toggle` on your `<a>` tag in the bootstrap code.